# Run an executable without showing in "top"

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, process

I need to run an executable in background on a server, however, it takes some parameter that I do not want to expose to others. I wonder if there is any way that I can wrap this executable in another app, or preferably just by using MATLAB, that the actual executable will not be shown in `top` command?

I need to hide three things, 1) the parameter of, 2) the path to, 3) the CPU usage of the executable. For the CPU usage, I do not intend to trick the system to show a constant 0% percent, but I want to let the usage been shown in the wrapper app.

For example, I have an executable in `/secret_path/A`, which takes parameter `-password 123`, and consumes a constant 10% CPU usage, all these information will be very easy to be spotted if I type `top` in another terminal window. I want to create another executable, for example in `~/B`, which hard code path and parameters of `A`, so I can just run `B` with no parameter to execute `A`, and instead showing a `A` record in `top`, it would be no trace of `A` and `B` will show 10% CPU usage in `top`.

Please suggest any way of doing that, without requiring root privilege, or why it is not possible.

Comment: I found it may possible and much easier on Windows, as PE can be embedded as resources, and once those resources are been read into memory, APIs can execute PEs directly from memory. I am not quite sure but it seems some vintage hack tools do - remember back to 2000s, loads of hack tools binds backdoors and genuine apps together and fool victims to execute? Not sure if it's possible on Linux :(

Comment: I've seen a lot of applications that accomplish this by allowing input of options/parameters through stdin or a file. [MySQL has this option for password input](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-security-user.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in a virtual machine. That way not only the path can be hidden but the executable itself won't have to exist on the file system. If you run top you will see the VM using the CPU, which shouldn't be a problem for you since apparently you only want to hide the path of the program.

Comment: Thanks. I could not run a VM for obvious reason: I do not have root privilege. But even if I could, it is still be out of my scope - e.g. I cannot access files on local drive, and heavy performance overhead. I am trying to find a way of binding two executables together, and shows only one item in `top`. 
PS: found a potential solution http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967 but haven't found a way to embed executable and make it executes.